# Mysql, ranking users by percentage

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this that keeps a total score of a history exam for students.

```
+----+---------------+-------+---------+-
| id | name          | history |  rank  | 
+----+---------------+-------+---------+-
|  1 | yngiid        |    97   |        | 
|  2 | viyrp         |   217   |        | 
|  3 | pae           |   599   |        | 
|  4 | spohl         |   284   |        | 
|  5 | shl           |   295   |        | 
|  6 | okeer         |    73   |        | 
|  7 | jmaany        |   657   |        | 
|  8 | hxt           |    80   |        | 
|  9 | yanier        |   599   |        | 
+----+---------------+-------+----------+-
```

The history field as you can see contains the total score the student . Now, I would like to rank the students by their scores as in, the higher the points the lower the rank, but only using percentage. Which means, user can be ranked from 1 - 100 only, basically similar to what stackoverflow has on the profile page, where it says .. `top 1%`

I tried something like this.

```
SELECT NAME, HISTORY, ROUND(history / 100) AS percentage FROM test ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

For which I was only able to get this.

```
name    HISTORY  percentage  
------  -------  ------------
jmaany      657             7
yanier      599             6
pae         599             6
shl         295             3
spohl       284             3
viyrp       217             2
yngiid       97             1
yngiid       97             1
okeer        73             1
yngiid       97             1
hxt          80             1
yngiid       97             1
```

The above is wrong, because (1) percentage should be from 1 - 100% and user with the highest `HISTORY` points should get the lowest percentage, so as to say `TOP 1%` or something similar.

Here is a sample table dump if it helps.

```
create table `test` (
    `id` int (11),
    `name` varchar (765),
    `history` int (11),
    `rank` int (11)
); 

insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values
('1','yngiid','97',NULL),
('2','viyrp','217',NULL),
('3','pae','599',NULL),
('4','spohl','284',NULL),
('5','shl','295',NULL),
('6','okeer','73',NULL),
('7','jmaany','657',NULL),
('8','hxt','80',NULL),
('9','yanier','599',NULL);
```

Comment: On what does your percentage should be calculated ? You need a reference value. There are only 2 reference values for the data you provided: either the sum of all history points, or the ranking position compared to others students. You should be more explicit. Show the final data you want

Comment: Also I don't see the logic behind this : if the higher the points the lesser the rank (that's logical), why would people with the most points would got the lowest percentage ??? That makes no sense unless you explain clearly what your reference value is

Comment: @ThomasG I don't know. Maths is a puzzle for me, but you do understand what I need. Isn't is possible to get the highest scorer, the lowest and make percentage out of it.

Comment: I precisely **don't** understand what you need. Read "Calculation" of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage to understand that we are missing : _The percent value is computed by multiplying the numeric value of **the ratio** by 100._ The ratio is a division, we don't know exactly on what the division should be operated from what you asked. And if I have a few ideas of what it might be (refer to my first comment), I dont see any of them that might return the lower  percentage for the highest points

Comment: @ThomasG isn't is possible to get the average score from the `test.history` then use it as a ratio?

Comment: This should help you to better define what you want if @Ivan answer don't fit your needs : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e20d5/18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> basically similar to what stackoverflow has on the profile page, where it says .. top 1%

The logic stackoverflow displays its top `1%`, etc. rank is quit easy to write. It means actually that the user is **among top `1%` of all users**. First for every user we have to determine the number of users that have rating (`history`) greater or equal. Then apply simple formula `numberOfUsersHavingGreaterOrEqualRating / numberofTotalUsers * 100`.

```
SET @total= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stud);
select s1.*, concat('TOP ', floor(nge / @total * 100), '%') as percent 
from stud s1
join (select s1.id, count(s2.id) as nge
    from stud s1
    join stud s2
    on s1.history <= s2.history
    group by s1.id) as s2
on s1.id = s2.id
order by history desc
```

[Play with it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d257d/48)

Comment: Ok, will test it, just emptied database, need some time to refill. just curious about one thing for now, why are all data at the interval of similar number. 11, 22, 33, 44 .. are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @ANW, yes. The number of users is only 9, so if I'm the first one it means that I'm among the first 1/9 part of all users or among the first `11%` of all users.

Comment: I tried it just now, I had to wait for my laptop to finish fetching stuff, anyway .. there is still a funny issue that is bugging me. I have over 4K records, and your script works except that it starts from `TOP 0%` and ends with `TOP 100%`. So, the `0%` kinda, doesn't make sense, so I added `+ 1` inside `floor(nge / @total * 100 + 1)` and as you might have guessed, it worked but with a minor issue. Now, the `100%` gets changed to `101%`. Is there a way to solve this little issue?

Comment: @ANW, yes. try to use CEIL instead of FLOOR in the code from my answer. Make sure no `+ 1` you've added before. It all about converting float numbers to integer.